# android "could not execute method of the activity" NullPointerException, but why?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout

In an activity that initially has only a title and a "+"-Button, I want to add LinearLayouts containing some more Views every time I click on the button.

I have no particular idea how to solve this, so I tried following:
There are a maximum of seven LinearLayouts to add, so I added them in the layout-xml-file and set them all to `android:visibility="gone"`

This is my layout-xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_ppe2" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        >

         (...)

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bt_ppe2_newset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickAddNewSet"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        />

        (...)

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/lin_ppe2_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">
            (...)
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/lin_ppe2_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">
            (...)
        </LinearLayout>

        (...)

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

There are LinearLayouts lin_ppe2_2 - lin_ppe2_8, which are the seven ones to set visible one after the other by clicking on the button.

Now in `onClickAddNewSet` I got following (`int counter` is initialized =1):

```
public void onClickAddNewSet(View v){
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.all_completed_bets, null);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.layout_ppe2);
        LinearLayout layout2 = null;
        switch(counter){
        case 1:
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_2);
            break;
        case 2:
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_3);
            break;
        case 3:
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_4);
            break;
        case 4: 
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_5);
            break;
        case 5:
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_6);
            break;
        case 6:
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_7);
            break;
        case 7: 
            layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_8);
            break;
        }
        if(counter>0 && counter <8){
            layout2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        }
        counter++;  
    }
```

That gives me always the mentioned error with a `NullPointerException` at the line `layout2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);`. I also tried

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.layout_ppe2);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_2);
layout2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

to check if the error occurs because the layout2 is initialized with null, but the counter works fine (I tested it with `setText(counter)` to the activity title-TextView). So now I have really no clue why this is getting me this `NullPointerException`. Am I overlooking something really obvious? Or are there better ways to achieve my goal? Note: I do not only have to add this LinearLayouts, later I must read out some values too (there are 2 EditText in each LinearLayout).

Comment: So you're saying that it's not finding the `lin_ppe2_2` layout?

Comment: Try using findViewByID instead of the the layout.findViewById

Answer (score -1):

Try changing
`<android:visibility="gone">`
to
`<android:visibility="invisible">`

I believe the `gone` attribute forces it to be completely ignored during layout, you want it to be laid out but not visible.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of inflating a new Scrollview instance, just manipulate the actual Scrollview attached to your activity.

So change all the `scrollview.findViewById()` and `layout.findViewById()` to just a call to `findViewById()` with no pre-fixed qualifiers.  This way you'll get a reference to the actual layout objects the user is viewing when they pressed the button.